# How do I make a system call and reload a file in a Visual Studio 2010 macro?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, vba

As you read this, though I have pretty good experience in C++ and Java, please keep in mind that I am a complete beginner when it comes to VB.  :)

Here is one idea of what I want to do:

```
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit Off
Imports System
Imports EnvDTE
Imports EnvDTE80
Imports EnvDTE90
Imports EnvDTE90a
Imports EnvDTE100
Imports System.Diagnostics

Public Module RecordingModule


    Sub TemporaryMacro()
// what is the right way to declare and define filename?
        dim String filename = DTE.ActiveDocument.FullName();
        DTE.ActiveDocument.Save()
// how do I make a system call, I'm pretty sure this is not correct
        System("astyle.exe " + filename);
// reload the formatted file, but how?
    End Sub
End Module
```

Alternatively, if I cannot reload it, I could do something like:

```
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit Off
Imports System
Imports EnvDTE
Imports EnvDTE80
Imports EnvDTE90
Imports EnvDTE90a
Imports EnvDTE100
Imports System.Diagnostics

Public Module RecordingModule


    Sub TemporaryMacro()
// what is the right way to declare and define filename?
        dim String filename = DTE.ActiveDocument.FullName();
        DTE.ActiveDocument.Save()
        DTE.ActiveDocument.Close()
// how do I make a system call, I'm pretty sure this is not correct
        System("astyle.exe " + filename);
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("File.Open",filename);
    End Sub
End Module
```

I don't much like that though as it will cause the windows to close/reopen and I will probably loose all of my undo history.

Can anyone give me some guidance here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A system call can be done with `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("executable.exe", "args")`
If the modified Document is currently open visual studio will ask you if you want to reload it.
If you close if before the operation you can reload it with `DTE.ItemOperations.OpenFile("filename")`

Comment: Thanks, this got me exactly to where I wanted to be: